# Is it possible to trigger mouseover on body load

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I need to trigger mouseover event on body load. I have done the below code:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#outer").trigger("mouseover");

$( "#outer" ).mouseover(function() {
alert("rrrrr");
  $( "#log" ).append( "<div>Handler for .mouseover() called.</div>" );
});


});

</script>

<div id="outer">
  Outer
  <div id="inner">
    Inner
  </div>
</div>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

But it's not working. Any help please?

Comment: You're triggering it before adding a function to the handler?

Comment: @Danny how will I add a function? If You know the solution, help me please.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#outer").mouseover(function () {
        alert("rrrrr");
        $("#log").append("<div>Handler for .mouseover() called.</div>");
    }).trigger("mouseover");
});`

Comment: @ripa - Just move `$("#outer").trigger("mouseover");` *after* your mouseover handler code.

Comment: @Danny, ripa uses `$(document).ready(function(){`, this means that the whole code will be executed when the html is loaded, doesn't it?

Comment: @user3132718 - the dom is ready, but that doesn't mean that the event handlers are going to do anything until they've had the function added to them. ripa had all the pieces, just in the wrong order. Add the event handler, and then trigger it, and I think you're in business.  Which is what Arun P Johny did in a single chain.

Answer (score 1):

You are possibly triggering the code before the body is actually wrote to the page. I made up a JSFiddle and got it working putting the trigger after the function. Not sure why but it works.

```
$( "#outer" ).mouseover(function() {
alert("rrrrr");
  $( "#log" ).append( "<div>Handler for .mouseover() called.</div>" );
});

$("#outer").trigger("mouseover");
```

here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meehanman/WDaa6/)